# How to deploy a C# & Python joint program

Tags: c#, python, deployment, vsto, installshield

Thanks in advance to anyone who take time to look at my question.

I am now trying to deploy an Excel AddIn program written by c# and python. Generally, it's a VSTO program. In detail, c# is used to build the Winform, including ribbon, tabs and buttons, python is to do the calculation.

For example, in one form I built called manipulation, c# will record the data range I selected. Then, behind the form, it is python(like pandas) who does the data manipulation. When I press the 'reformat' button on the form, c# will connect python interpreter, pass the data range it holds to python and let python do the data manipulation. At last, I let Xlwings to write the calculation results into excel.

The way I connect c# and Python is mainly based on https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/C-and-Python-interprocess-171378ee, the key idea of this connection is giving c# the absolute path of my python interpreter and scripts, like:

```
string python = @"C:\python.exe";
string myPythonApp = @"D:\Manipulation.py";
```

All the above idea works fine until I finished the codes and try to distribute my program. I got absolutely confused about how could I deploy all the c# and python codes into an installer, like MSI or EXE.

My ultimate goal is: the user don't need to install python and c# when he/ she uses my software. In order to do this, I guess not only I need to pack all the c# and python codes, but also a virtual Python environment(I already created one virtual environment in the same folder as my addin project) should be included. My whole project looks like this:
[My project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cy0rI.png)

My questions:

1. How to deploy my program? I am now trying to use Installshield to do this. Would anyone who is experienced on deployment give me some ideas?
2. Even if I could successfully deploy my program, how to do to make sure c# could always find the python interpreter and scripts? The absolute path is apparently not OK to do this.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Not sure about #1, but for #2, this should help: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0514/#structure

Comment: @itsme86 I have also seen like: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE in install shield, I'll try to see if this can work. Thanks!

Comment: For Python 3.5 there are portable/embedded distribution packages. They are relatively small and you can include them in your own installation package. They do however not support the installation of Python packages via pip, but you could setup the environment manually and include it in your distribution.

Comment: @code_onkel Thank you! I already did this bu using Visual Studio PTVS, which is very convenient to create a virtual python environment manuly. Now, the problem I am facing is how to deploy this environment together with the c# code.

Comment: @BingjieHan, so what did you eventually do?

Comment: @NoChance Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39732390/c-sharp-add-folders-to-resources and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40114767/deploy-vsto-into-one-single-installer to see if these links can help you.