# deploy VSTO into one single Installer

Tags: installation, vsto, clickonce

I have deployed a VSTO application by using ClickOnce and I got this:

[image: publish folder of ClickOnce]

This installer works real fine.

However, what I really want is **one single installer, like a single .exe file or a single .msi file**, so that it would be much convinenet to distribute.

I guess I have to pack all the dll, xml, vsto and exe into one single installer. Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks in advance to anyone who has taken time to look at my problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this https://github.com/bovender/VstoAddinInstaller
A few years ago I wrote a few installers for VSTO projects via Inno Setup. There are also other players like (all paid) Advanced Installer, InstallShield and probably many others. 
There is also [VS installer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442767.aspx) but I've never used it (but still should be possible)

Comment: Sorry about my late response! I will try and see your solution.

Comment: Does VstoAddinInstaller pack an Vsto application into only one .exe or .msi file? Thank you!

Comment: Sorry I haven't tried but given the fact that I use Inno setup for creating one exe file (the VstoAddInInstaller is using it as well) I believe it will be one single exe

Comment: Thank you! I will try and see, sorry this takes time, once I found this works fine, I will accept your answer.

Comment: This did work! Your answer helped me a lot! Thank you!